# Does Google take into account page title changes due to JavaScript?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

One of my pages is set up so that the initial page title is just some placeholder title, and it changes after an AJAX call.

Here's what the process looks like:

1. Initial page load
2. AJAX call to retrieve some data
3. Page title changed according to AJAX data

Does Google take page title changes into account? Or does Google only look at what the initial page title is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question being quite subjective to the code that is being implemented. I would recommend using Fetch & Render in Google Webmasters - [Link to fetch and render](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch)

After fetching and rendering, click on the result and click on the 'Fetching' tab, you will see what source code Google saw while trying to fetch your website.

[image]

Comment: That fetch/render tool is really helpful.  It seems that Google did not take the AJAX call into account.  I have to modify the page to remove the AJAX call.

Comment: Awesome, now you just have to get that right and you are good to go.